# How to import and read a json file into Vue / Gridsome main.js

Tags: vue.js, gridsome

I'm working on a project that is using Vue / Gridsome and have a question about importing a config.json file with  `import './config.json'`  into the `main.js` file.

The `config.json` files is as follows:

```
{
  "brand": "Name"
  "company_no": "12345678"
  "charity_no": "87654321"
  "registered_address": "25 Riverdale House: London: SE13 7LW"
  "contact_email": "support@name.com"
}
```

The `main.js` file is as follows:

```
export default function (Vue, { router, head, isClient }) {
  Vue.component('Layout', DefaultLayout)
  Vue.component('Page', PageLayout)
  Vue.use(InfiniteLoading)

  // General

  head.meta.push({
    name    : 'description',
    content : config.brand // I'd like to place the json value here
  })

  // ...
```

Will I need to install a plugin which parses the JSON to be able to read these properties, and how would I go about accessing the brand value as an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do something like:

```js
import configJson from './config.json';

const config = JSON.parse(configJson);
```

Then you can access the data with `config.brand` for example.

More about `JSON parse`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

**EDIT**
It works if you have `webpack >= 2.0.0`

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/

Otherwise you could create a js file and export the json from there:

**config.js**

```js
export default
{
  // put json here
}
```